# Refresh/ update ILNumerics Plot

Tags: ilnumerics

I want to update/ refresh a graph created with ILNumerics. I do not understand how to manipulate the data set, after the plot is created.

Here, http://ilnumerics.net/line-plots.html a simple example is given to plot two data sets. Now (for example, when a button is pushed) I want to create a new set of data points for the blue line and update the graph respectively.

How do I get access to the 'old blue' data set, how do I manipulate it, and how do I refresh the graph afterwards?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the line plots a tag. It helps to find them in the scene later.
2. When button is pressed, locate and change the line plot by

.

```
var lp = ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILLinePlot>(yourTag);

lp.Line.Positions.Update([your data as 3 x m matrix]); 

lp.Configure(); 
ilPanel1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thank's for your help. Unfortunately it turned out, that ILnumerics is to slow for my purpose. I'll try OpenGL.

Comment: This is strange! ILNumerics actually uses OpenGl for rendering. May you have used their GDI renderer? Or done something wrong?

Comment: I tried OpenGL for ILnumerics first, but I had some trouble, because even the examples didn't work (ill display of axis and so on). However, when I switched the same example to GDI, the problems vanished. I searched a bit the internet and found out, that some people using an Intel graphics card had also similar problems. Now I changed my code and use OpenGL directly to visualize my results, this works fine for me.

Comment: Right. ILNumerics had problems with IntelHD graphics earlier on. They should be gone since 4.0.